# Can I detect if my Windows 8 application is running?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a background task that I want to behave differently if the application is running. How can I detect if my Windows 8 store application is running?

Comment: I think this has already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342640/how-to-check-from-scheduled-agent-if-the-foreground-app-is-running

Comment: Additionally, use a mutex to avoid any case where two threads are accessing the same resources.

Comment: The linked duplicate is about windows phone and does not have a good answer, hence I am not voting to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want your app to behave differently when it is in focus, here is how I handled it in my code -

In your class constructor -

```
CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Activated += CoreWindowOnActivated;
```

Then, add the implementation -

```
private void CoreWindowOnActivated(CoreWindow sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.WindowActivationState == CoreWindowActivationState.CodeActivated)
        {
               //add your app specific behavior here
        }
}
```

You will also need to detach the event when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this in WinForms I would use a Mutex,

foreground app can lock it

When the foreground app exits for any reason, then windows will unlock the Mutex

The background app can check if the Mutex is locked.

Sorry I don’t know I this work for a windows store app.